# When testing code in the Python IDLE, why is my newly saved code not running after making updates to it in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-idle

For context, I am editing a simple script that outputs stock information to a Pandas dataframe.  I am currently editing the script itself within VS Code, and build it there.  I started to notice that my one function was no longer returning output, just returning a blank dataframe.  (That function is "combined_events").  I noticed that it was using the depreciated "append" function from pandas, and I made a code change to use pandas.concat to combine dataframes.  When I made the changes and saved the Python script, I restarted the shell, and re-imported necessary modules to the shell.  When I retried with the new edits, the dataframe still returned blank.

I do not have Git or a dedicated version control, as I just use this script for some personal calculations.  Sample of what I am seeing is below:

```
from projects.api import stock_functions as sf
l = ['O','STAG','MAIN','LAND','PECO','SCHD']
e = sf.combined_events(l)
e
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
import pandas as pd
def combined_events(list_arg):
    appEvents = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(0,len(list_arg)):
        try:
            events = sf.get_event_data_to_dataframe(list_arg[i])
            appEvents = pd.concat([appEvents,events],ignore_index=True)
            #appEvents = appEvents._append(events)
        except:
            pass
    
    return appEvents

e = combined_events(l)
e
   Ticker       Date     Event  Amount
0       O 2023-12-29  DIVIDEND   0.257
1       O 2023-11-30  DIVIDEND   0.256
2       O 2023-10-31  DIVIDEND   0.256
3       O 2023-09-29  DIVIDEND   0.256
4       O 2023-08-31  DIVIDEND   0.256
..    ...        ...       ...     ...
63   PECO 2023-02-17  DIVIDEND   0.093
64   SCHD 2023-12-06  DIVIDEND   0.742
65   SCHD 2023-09-20  DIVIDEND   0.655
66   SCHD 2023-06-21  DIVIDEND   0.665
67   SCHD 2023-03-22  DIVIDEND   0.597

[68 rows x 4 columns]
```

I tried saving the Python script multiple times, restarted the shell IDLE, re-imported the module.  I f I create the function within the IDLE and run it with other function from same script, it works within the IDLE.  See code sample above.

Comment: May be difference between formatting: tabs and spaces?

Comment: May not be related to what you're asking but it's good practice to add an else block to your try statement. Maybe something like this try `events = sf.get_event_data_to_dataframe(list_arg[i])` except SomeError pass else `appEvents = pd.concat([appEvents,events],ignore_index=True)`

Comment: If I understand, you are editing .../projects/api/stock_functions.py in VS_Code, saving, and running the above in IDLE's Shell.  It would seem that sf.combined_events code is not the same as what you enter in Shell.  To check, use File => Open Module and enter `projects.api.stock_functions` to load the code being inported into an IDLE editor to check the `combined_events` code there.  Also, use right click `Copy with prompts` after selection code and output in Shell to have your input marked with prompts.

Comment: @Terry, 
Yes, I am editing the code in VS Code, saving, and running in IDLE.  I will test out what you have outlined.  Thank you